# Retrieving item between two arrays of object with complex conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, performance, optimization

I got two lists of objects :

```
let list1 = [{id: '1', status: 'use', comment: 'xxxx'}, {id: '2', status: 'ready', comment: 'yyyy'}, {id: '3', status: 'ready', comment: 'zzzz'}];
let list2 = [{uid: '1', elec: 60}, {uid: '2', elec: 60}, {uid: '10', elec: 60}, {uid: '3', elec: 40}];
```

What i want is to retrieve an object of list2 that have elec > 50 and the same uid than one item id of the list1 only if the item of the list1 have a status == "ready". Also, i want to add to this item the parameter 'comment' from the object of the list1.

In this exemple, my result value would be : {uid: '2', elect: 60, comment: 'yyyy'}.

I did this :

```
  let list1Filtered = list1.filter(itemList1 => itemList1.status == 'ready');
  let list2Filtered = list2.filter(itemList2 => itemList2.elec > 50);
  var result;

  for ( let  itemList1Filtered of list1Filtered ) {
    for ( let  itemList2Filtered of list2Filtered ) {
      if (!result && itemList1Filtered.id == itemList2Filtered.uid) {
        result = itemList2Filtered;
        result.comment = itemList1Filtered.comment;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
```

I want to know if there is a more elegant and/or more sophisticated way to do this in Javascript.

Comment: What if more than one items fitted the criteria ?

Comment: Also your `> 60` means that none of the items would match in the example. you would need `>= 60`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli : the first one should be selected. I used !result in the if set result only 1 time. 
For the 60 you are correct, it was a typo and i fixed it with `> 50`. Sorry for that

Comment: Instead of checking `!result` you can just do `return result;` directly in the if statement in the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect wanted comments from list1 and reduce `list2` with a check for the value of `elec` and if an item exist from the other list. Then return a new object.

This approach needs only two loops.

```js
const
    list1 = [{ id: '1', status: 'use', comment: 'xxxx' }, { id: '2', status: 'ready', comment: 'yyyy' }, { id: '3', status: 'ready', comment: 'zzzz' }],
    list2 = [{ uid: '1', elec: 60 }, { uid: '2', elec: 60 }, { uid: '10', elec: 60 }, { uid: '3', elec: 40 }],
    l1 = list1.reduce((r, { id, status, comment }) => {
        if (status === 'ready') r[id] = { comment };
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = list2.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.elec > 50 && o.uid in l1) r.push({ ...o, ...l1[o.uid]})
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = {
    ...list2.filter(
    a => a.elec > 50 && a.uid === list1.filter(b => b.status === "ready")[0].id)[0],
    comments: list1.filter(b => b.status === "ready")[0].comment
}
```

Comment: @Aion I think this is the shortest it can get but it's basically also using two loops, just like your solution, which is imo already okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let list1 = [
  { id: '1', status: 'use', comment: 'xxxx' },
  { id: '2', status: 'ready', comment: 'yyyy' },
  { id: '3', status: 'ready', comment: 'zzzz' },
];
let list2 = [
  { uid: '1', elec: 60 },
  { uid: '2', elec: 60 },
  { uid: '10', elec: 60 },
  { uid: '3', elec: 40 },
];

let result = null;
let itemFound;

const filteredList = list2.filter((list2Item) => {
  if (!result) {
    itemFound =
      list2Item.elec > 50 &&
      list1.find(
        (list1Item) =>
          list2Item.uid === list1Item.id && list1Item.status === 'ready'
      );
    if (itemFound) {
      result = {
        uid: list2Item.uid,
        elect: list2Item.elec,
        comment: itemFound.comment,
      };
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```js
const list1 = [{
  id: '1',
  status: 'use',
  comment: 'xxxx'
}, {
  id: '2',
  status: 'ready',
  comment: 'yyyy'
}, {
  id: '3',
  status: 'ready',
  comment: 'zzzz'
}];

const list2 = [{
  uid: '1',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '2',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '10',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '3',
  elec: 40
}];

const filteredList = list2.filter(item => {
  const readyItemsList1 = list1.filter(item => item.status === 'ready').map(item => item.id);
  return item.elec > 50 && readyItemsList1.indexOf(item.uid) > -1
}).map(item => {
  const comment = list1.find(it => it.id === item.uid).comment;
  item.comment = comment;
  return item;
});

console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: doesn't add comment.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I miss that bit from the requirements; I will amend it immediately. Thanks for making me notice it.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can restructure your data. List1 convert it in object. And now we can find solution in O(n).
```

```js
let list1 = [{
  id: '1',
  status: 'use',
  comment: 'xxxx'
}, {
  id: '2',
  status: 'ready',
  comment: 'yyyy'
}, {
  id: '3',
  status: 'ready',
  comment: 'zzzz'
}];
let list2 = [{
  uid: '1',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '2',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '10',
  elec: 60
}, {
  uid: '3',
  elec: 40
}];
const itemList = {}
list1.forEach(item => {
  if (item.status === 'ready') {
    itemList[item.id] = item.comment
  }
});
const result = list2.filter(item => itemList[item.uid] && item.elec > 50).map(item => {
  item['comment'] = itemList[item.uid]
  return item
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

`filter` and `map` will help you.

`filter` can select items fit some criteria, and `map` let you change the data to pick.

For `list1`, select item with `status` equals `'ready'`, then take only `id`.

```
var ready_id_array = list1.filter(item=>item.status == 'ready').map(item=>item.id);
```

For `list2`, check item that its `uid` contained in `ready_id_array`, and `elec` larger than 50.

```
var result = list2 .filter(item => ready_id_array.indexOf(item.uid) > -1 && item.elec > 50);
```

to append the comment, a dictionary is created and then put comment back to result

```
var comment_dictionary = list1.reduce((a,x) => ({...a, [x.id]: x.comment}), {});
result.forEach(item => item.comment = comment_dictionary[item.uid]);
```

and you will have the result.

```
[{uid: "2", elec: 60, comment: "yyyy"}]
```

Comment: doesn't get the comment.

Comment: Right, but with that i'm missing the comment from list1 ;)